# Application.DoEvents memory leak?

Tags: c#, html, memory-leaks

I'm running through a list of websites and grabbing their content. I do this by first getting the webpage as a string, then attempting to shove it into a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser object through its DocumentText property.

Here's a portion of the code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(siteAddress))
                webReq = WebRequest.Create(siteAddress);

            WebResponse webRes = webReq.GetResponse();

            Stream streamResponse = webRes.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            Char[] readBuff = new Char[256];
            int count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
            string fullHTML = "";
            while (count > 0)
            {
                String outputData = new String(readBuff, 0, count);
                fullHTML += outputData;
                count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
            }

            //Close the Stream object.
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();

            //Release the HttpWebResponse Resource.
            webRes.Close();

            //Convert string to HTML document                
            WebBrowser webControl = new WebBrowser();
            webControl.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webControl.DocumentText = fullHTML;
            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            } while (webControl.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
```

This kinda works - I can pull apart the HTML by filtering the tags and so on. The issue is, as the topic name implies, is that there's some sort of memory leak going on, specifically during the Application.DoEvents() loop. Does anyone know what's going on? The memory usage doesn't go up much until it finishes the `do` loop, then RAM usage jumps up about 800kb. I'm looking through a few thousand pages so it's a bit alarming to find my program using hundreds of megs in a short space of time.

Is there a simpler solution to grabbing a full HTML document from a site which allows for in-code DOM traversal while not leaking memory?

Comment: `fullHTML += outputData` - this is pretty inefficient, as it clones the string on each pass through the loop. You can replace this `while` loop with a call to `streamRead.ReadToEnd()`. Also, enclose `webRes`, `streamRead` and `streamResponse` in `using` blocks, and drop the calls to `Close()`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will keep them in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to achieve the outcome you're looking for.  By the way, I suspect it's the web browser control which is leaking - if the control hasn't fully loaded and you load something else, it'll just leak the memory of the previous page (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you, along with the others who suggested this. I was contemplating it but was looking for a Microsoft solution, but this works brilliantly!

Answer (score 1):

Does the memory not release when your application closes? I would expect memory usage to increase when a page is being downloaded.

Comment: It certainly does release. In fact, downloading the content into string doesn't appear to increase the mem usage by any significant factor (at least going by what Task Manager shows).

Comment: @MHTri: That is what I expected to hear. In this case, you don't really have a memory leak, but you are nonetheless using memory (by downloading the page content). As @Tim Robinson mentioned, you could use the html agility pack to possibly avoid some of the load (by not downloading images, etc. perhaps?) I don't actually have experience with this, but it may be something to look into.

Comment: While I am downloading content and thus increasing memory, I find it hard to believe that on the first page download it would be at 35MB and by the 1000th or so page the mem usage would have increased to over 500MB (arbitrary numbers to illustrate the alarming amount of memory in use). It was only when Visual Studio came back with a 'Corrupted Memory' error that I saw my program using 1.5GB of RAM. Wouldn't the usage stay constant throughout if I was to create a new WebBrowser instance (after nulling the old one) after every loop?

Comment: @MHTri: I see. Are you calling `webControl.Dispose()` (or putting it in a `using` block)? Simply setting it to null will not release everything it uses

Comment: I am not doing either, so this is probably where I am going wrong. I'll keep this in mind if HTMLAgilityPack isn't working well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a memory leak with `Application.DoEvents()` but there is indeed a much simpler comparatively light weight option: Use the [HtmlagilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead, which will enable you to do all the HTML parsing you need without having to instantiate a `WebBrowser` object.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect memory to be used as the page is loaded into the WebBrowser control. It's only a memory leak if that memory never gets released; given the complexity of IE, I wouldn't like to guess when that memory will be freed up.

> Is there a simpler solution to grabbing a full HTML document from a site which allows for in-code DOM?

To extract content from an HTML page in memory, without loading it into a WebBrowser control first, try the HTML Agility Pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/